# problema en el header al fijarlo

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, gulp

soy nuevo y hace poco termine una pagina web aplicando HTML/CSS/JavaScript/SASS y bueno me surgieron varios problemas como que al fijar el header, este desaparece pero al hacer scroll vuelve a aparecer pero parpadea dependiendo del zoom que la hagas(no sabia de este error hasta que hize zoom)  y lo ultimo es que sigue apareciendo la barra de reproduccion del video que coloque al principio
dejo el repo para que lo vean:

https://github.com/Maurof18/FestivalMusica.git

y me gustaria que las correcciones hagan la colocaran aca y bueno tambien que esta bien y mal del proyecto asi poder mejorar desde ya gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: solo como comentario del proyecto, y que te servirá para todos tus proyectos, la carpeta ``node_modules`` no se debe subir al repositorio por distintas razones, una de las principales es que es un directorio muy pesado que se crea siempre cuando alguien hace clone a tu proyecto, por lo que no es necesario que exista ahi, te recomiendo crear un archivo .gitignore en la raíz de tu proyecto y ahi agregar el path de node_modules

Comment: Muestra un [repro] en la pregunta misma, no a través de enlaces externos. Lee [ask] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.